# MLlib classification example stops in stage 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

**EDIT**:

I tried using the text from Gabriel's answer and got spam features: 9 and ham features: 13. I tried changing the HashingTF to numFeatures = 9, then 13, then created one for each. Then the program stopped at "count at DataValidators.scala:38" just like before.

Completed Jobs(4)
count at 21 (spamFeatures)
count at 23 (hamFeatures)
count at 28 (trainingData.count())
first at GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm at 34 (val model = lrLearner.run(trainingData)

1) Why are the features being counted by lines, as in the code it is being split by spaces (" ")

2) Two things I see dift from my code and Gabriel's code: 
a) I don't have anything about logger, but that shouldn't be an issue...
b) My files are located on hdfs(hdfs://ip-abc-de-.compute.internal:8020/user/ec2-user/spam.txt), once again shouldn't be an issue, but not sure if there's something i'm missing...

3) How long should I let it run for? I've let it run for at least 10 minutes with :local[2]..

I'm guessing at this point it might be some sort of issue with my Spark/MLlib setup? Is there an even simpler program I can run to see if there is a set up issue with MLLib? I have been able to run other spark streaming/sql jobs berfore...

Thanks!

[reposted from spark community]

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to run this MLlib example from Learning Spark:
https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/MLlib.scala#L48

Things I'm doing differently:

1) instead of their spam.txt and normal.txt I have text files with 200 words...nothing huge at all and just plain text, with periods, commas, etc.

3) I've used numFeatures = 200, 1000 and 10,000

Error: I keep getting stuck when I try to run the model (based off details from ui below):

val model = new LogisticRegressionWithSGD().run(trainingData)

It will freeze on something like this:

[Stage 1:==============>                                            (1 + 0) / 4]

Some details from webui:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:910)
org.apache.spark.mllib.util.DataValidators$$anonfun$1.apply(DataValidators.scala:38)
org.apache.spark.mllib.util.DataValidators$$anonfun$1.apply(DataValidators.scala:37)
org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm$$anonfun$run$2.apply(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:161)
org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm$$anonfun$run$2.apply(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:161)
scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.forall(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:70)
scala.collection.immutable.List.forall(List.scala:84)
org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:161)
org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:146)
$line21.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
$line21.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
$line21.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
$line21.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
$line21.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
$line21.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
$line21.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
$line21.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
$line21.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
$line21.$eval.$print(<console>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong...any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this question, I wasn't aware of these examples so I downloaded them and tested them. What I see is that the git repository contains files with a lot of html code, it works, but you will end up adding 100 features which is possibly why you're not getting consistent results, since your own files contain much less features. What I did to test this works without html code was to remove the HTML code from spam.txt and ham.txt as follows:

ham.txt=

```
Dear Spark Learner, Thanks so much for attending the Spark Summit 2014!       
Check out videos of talks from the summit at ...
Hi Mom, Apologies for being late about emailing and forgetting to send you  
the package.  I hope you and bro have been ...
Wow, hey Fred, just heard about the Spark petabyte sort.  I think we need to  
take time to try it out immediately ...
Hi Spark user list, This is my first question to this list, so thanks in  
advance for your help!  I tried running ...
Thanks Tom for your email.  I need to refer you to Alice for this one.  I    
haven&#39;t yet figured out that part either ...
Good job yesterday!  I was attending your talk, and really enjoyed it.  I   
want to try out GraphX ...
Summit demo got whoops from audience!  Had to let you know. --Joe
```

spam.txt=

```
 Dear sir, I am a Prince in a far kingdom you have not heard of.  I want to 
 send you money via wire transfer so please ...
 Get Viagra real cheap!  Send money right away to ...
 Oh my gosh you can be really strong too with these drugs found in the     
 rainforest. Get them cheap right now ...
 YOUR COMPUTER HAS BEEN INFECTED!  YOU MUST RESET YOUR PASSWORD.  Reply to    
 this email with your password and SSN ...
 THIS IS NOT A SCAM!  Send money and get access to awesome stuff really   
 cheap and never have to ...
```

Then use bellow modifed MLib.scala, make sure you have log4j referenced in your project to redirect output to a file instead of the console, so you basically need to run twice, in first run watch the output by printing the # of features in spam and ham you can then set the correct # of features (instead of 100) I used 5.

```
package com.oreilly.learningsparkexamples.scala

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.HashingTF
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object MLlib {

private val logger = Logger.getLogger("MLlib")

def main(args: Array[String]) {
    logger.info("This is spark in Windows")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"Book example: Scala").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
    //val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"Book example: Scala")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    // Load 2 types of emails from text files: spam and ham (non-spam).
    // Each line has text from one email.
    val spam = sc.textFile("spam.txt")
    val ham = sc.textFile("ham.txt")
    // Create a HashingTF instance to map email text to vectors of 5 (not 100) features.
    val tf = new HashingTF(numFeatures = 5)
    // Each email is split into words, and each word is mapped to one feature.
    val spamFeatures = spam.map(email => tf.transform(email.split(" ")))
    println ("features in spam " + spamFeatures.count())
    val hamFeatures = ham.map(email => tf.transform(email.split(" ")))
    println ("features in ham " + ham.count())
    // Create LabeledPoint datasets for positive (spam) and negative (ham) examples.
    val positiveExamples = spamFeatures.map(features => LabeledPoint(1, features))
    val negativeExamples = hamFeatures.map(features => LabeledPoint(0, features))
    val trainingData = positiveExamples ++ negativeExamples
    trainingData.cache() // Cache data since Logistic Regression is an iterative algorithm.
    // Create a Logistic Regression learner which uses the LBFGS optimizer.
    val lrLearner = new LogisticRegressionWithSGD()
    // Run the actual learning algorithm on the training data.
    val model = lrLearner.run(trainingData)
    // Test on a positive example (spam) and a negative one (ham).
    // First apply the same HashingTF feature transformation used on the training data.
    val ex1 = "O M G GET cheap stuff by sending money to ...";
    val ex2 = "Hi Dad, I started studying Spark the other ..."
    val posTestExample = tf.transform(ex1.split(" "))
    val negTestExample = tf.transform(ex2.split(" "))
    // Now use the learned model to predict spam/ham for new emails.
    println(s"Prediction for positive test example: ${ex1} : ${model.predict(posTestExample)}")
    println(s"Prediction for negative test example: ${ex2} : ${model.predict(negTestExample)}")
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

When I run this in the output I'm getting:

```
features in spam 5
features in ham 7
Prediction for positive test example: O M G GET cheap stuff by sending money    
to ... : 1.0
Prediction for negative test example: Hi Dad, I started studying Spark the    
other ... : 0.0
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel for the detailed explanation. Couple follow up questions as I was not able to run the program still...would you mind checking my edit in the main question, as its hard to ask in the comment? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Spark 1.5.2 on my local cluster.
My program stopped on "count at DataValidators.scala:40".
Resolved by running spark as "spark-submit --master local"

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem with Spark 1.5.2 on my local cluster. My program stopped on "count at DataValidators.scala:40". I was caching my training features. Removed caching (just did not call cache function) and it resolved. Not sure of actual cause though.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind doing so? As far as I know, the MLib iterative algorithms should run better with cached data